# Python: how to remove timezone from dictionary values?

Tags: python

I've a dictionary defined as follows. Its values are both str and datetime type.
How to loop through it and remove timezones?

```
{'Account': 'xxx', 'Group': 'yyy', 'CreationDate': pywintypes.datetime(2020, 12, 2, 15, 58, 28, 790000, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True)), 'EditDate': pywintypes.datetime(2020, 12, 16, 10, 46, 7, 519000, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True))}
```

I tried this way but I get error `'dict_values' object is not subscriptable` on `tmp = contacts_dict.values()[j]`:

```
contacts_dict_len = len(contacts_dict)

for j in range(0,contacts_dict_len):
    tmp = contacts_dict.values()[j]
    if isinstance(tmp, datetime.datetime):
        contacts_dict.values()[j] = tmp.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

PS: Removing timezones is needed in order to avoid following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion._localize_tso'
```

Comment: If you're defining the data, why not just *not* include the tzinfo? Also, if you're removing time zone info *just* to avoid an error, you're doing something wrong. Find out the real cause of the error -- don't just try to slap a bandaid on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python dictionaries are not subscriptable. Remove the timezones by directly addressing the key values that you wish to change instead of looping through them.